# Beamer content default top margin - how to suppress?

Tags: beamer

How do you suppress the top margin in the content box of the beamer frame?

This is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} % new 
\usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, cancel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor }

\tcbset{%
    noparskip,
    colback=gray!10, %background color of the box
    colframe=gray!40, %color of frame and title background
    coltext=black, %color of body text
    coltitle=black, %color of title text 
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    alerted/.style={coltitle=red, 
        colframe=gray!40},
    example/.style={coltitle=black, 
        colframe=green!20,             
        colback=green!5},
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.2 cm}}
\newcommand{\disponslide}[2]{%
    \alt<#1>{#2}{\phantom{#2}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Expansion}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        For all real numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
        \begin{align*}
        &(a+b)^2 =  a^2 + 2ab + b^2&&\\
        &(a+b)(a-b) =  a^2 - 2ab + b^2&&
        \end{align*}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{align*}
    (a+b)^2&= (a+b)(a+b)\\
    &= a^2+ab+ba+b^2\\
    &= a^2+2ab+b^2 \quad\text{(since ba=ab)}\\
    (a+b)(a-b)&= a^2-ab+ba-b^2 \\
    &= a^2-b^2 \quad\text{(since ba=ab)}
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

See below how there is a noticeable gap between formula box and the equations.
I never specified line breaks after the formula box and latex still puts in several lines breaks.
[image: What I get when I compile]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `[nobeforeafter]` as the options to `tcolorbox` to cancel those top and bottom spaces and the box is put in a paragraph with no space above and below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} % new
\usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, cancel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor }

\tcbset{%
    noparskip,
    colback=gray!10, %background color of the box
    colframe=gray!40, %color of frame and title background
    coltext=black, %color of body text
    coltitle=black, %color of title text
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    alerted/.style={coltitle=red,
        colframe=gray!40},
    example/.style={coltitle=black,
        colframe=green!20,
        colback=green!5},
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.2 cm}}
\newcommand{\disponslide}[2]{%
    \alt<#1>{#2}{\phantom{#2}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Expansion}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter]
        For all real numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
        \begin{align*}
        &(a+b)^2 =  a^2 + 2ab + b^2&&\\
        &(a+b)(a-b) =  a^2 - 2ab + b^2&&
        \end{align*}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{align*}
    (a+b)^2&= (a+b)(a+b)\\
    &= a^2+ab+ba+b^2\\
    &= a^2+2ab+b^2 \quad\text{(since ba=ab)}\\
    (a+b)(a-b)&= a^2-ab+ba-b^2 \\
    &= a^2-b^2 \quad\text{(since ba=ab)}
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with the keys `before skip`, `after skip`, `beforeafter skip` etc to have more control on them.